# Dynamic Time Warping Linear Algebra and Pseudocode Explanation

Tags: time-series

Can someone explain some questions I have about the pseudocode in [the Wikipedia article for Dynamic Time Warping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping)? (I'm talking about the implementation with the window constraint parameter `w`.

On the line `DTW[0, 0] := 0`, why are we setting the first element to zero after setting the entire matrix to infinity? I'm sure there's some reason, but I can't figure out why.

On the lines initializing the second set of for loops:

```
for i := 1 to n
    for j := max(1, i-w) to min(m, i+w)
```

why do we skip the first row/column? I get the bounding idea in the inner loop with the window constraint, but from what I understand, in DTW, not using the first column and first row is essential. Why?

Within the for loops:

```
cost := d(s[i], t[j])
DTW[i, j] := cost + minimum(DTW[i-1, j  ],    // insertion
                            DTW[i  , j-1],    // deletion
                            DTW[i-1, j-1])    // match
```

I understand the cost is the current distance between two elements in the respective time series, but what are we doing when we set `DTW[i, j]` to

```
cost + minimum(DTW[i-1, j  ],    // insertion
               DTW[i  , j-1],    // deletion
               DTW[i-1, j-1])    // match
```

I'm not the best at Dynamic Programming, so I don't understand this line as well. Why are each cases considered an insertion, deletion, and a match?

Finally, for the last line:

`return DTW[n, m]`

Why are we returning the last element? I thought DTW was supposed to return the aligned time series which I figured would be represented by the warping path in the matrix.